# On the shape of parabolas and connected second derivatives

Tags: calculus

If the second derivative of a function is constant, ‘a’, such that equation of function is the family of the form $y = ax^2 + bx +c$. Then does it follow that for any given ‘a’, all graphs of this family, i.e. the plotted parabolas, are similar figures.

Apologies, if this is a question with an obvious answer.

Many thanks in advance for any help given.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parabola), all (non-trivial?) parabolas are similar! Since scaling a parabola is equivalent to changing its $x^2$ term.

As for the example in your question, if two quadratics have the same $x^2$ coefficient, they are translations of each other. This can be seen by completing the square: by "shifting" the coordinates of the

Sorry if this would be better as a comment! I am a new user.